# JPQL Left Join on clause

Tags: left-join, jpql

I have several entities and want to do a join like this:

```
SELECT g FROM Gift g
LEFT JOIN Worker w ON g.receiver = w.person
WHERE ....
AND w.company = :companyId
```

The problem is that there's no direct connection between g.receiver who is a Person and w.person. I don't want to inner join them either, because a receiver of a gift may not be a worker of a company.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but i didn't find any solution in JPQL, it looks like if you don't have a mapped relation, you can't perform a left join.

I solved the problem with 2 query and a join implemented by code.

Another solution is a native query.

Comment: _"I solved the problem with 2 query and a join implemented by code."_ How did you do that? Pseudocode in the answer would be nice :)